# Telegram bot does not show anything inside the bot

Tags: python-telegram-bot

I wrote my Telegram bot, but commandHanler doesn't send anything inside the bot, but inside the terminal, it shows that someone hit /start
Thank you for telling me what to do

```
from telegram.ext import Updater,CommandHandler,MessageHandler
import logging

# Enable logging
logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s',
                    level=logging.INFO)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

Token='1226131623:uQiJSmRG7mwRsvj7Fc8iUWyuOkOy7eQ4qHC73KKl'
updater=Updater(token=Token,base_url="https://tapi.bale.ai/",use_context=True)
def start(update,contex):
    update.message.reply_text('hi')


dp=updater.dispatcher
dp.add_handler(CommandHandler("start",start))

updater.start_polling()
updater.idle()
```

out put terminal:

```
2023-09-29 02:11:11,822 - telegram.bot - DEBUG - Exiting: get_updates
2023-09-29 02:11:11,822 - telegram.bot - DEBUG - Entering: get_updates
2023-09-29 02:11:11,822 - telegram.ext.dispatcher - DEBUG - Processing Update: {'message': {'chat': {'id': 390486836, 'username': 'peyman201256', 'first_name': '', 'type': 'private'}, 'date': 1695940872, 'entities': [], 'new_chat_photo': [], 'new_chat_members': [], 'group_chat_created': False, 'channel_chat_created': False, 'photo': [], 'text': '/start', 'caption_entities': [], 'delete_chat_photo': False, 'message_id': 16, 'supergroup_chat_created': False, 'from': {'is_bot': False, 'username': 'peyman201256', 'first_name': '', 'id': , 'last_name': ''}}, 'update_id': 16}
2023-09-29 02:11:11,901 - telegram.bot - DEBUG - No new updates found.
```

I want it to give me an output inside the robot, which unfortunately it doesn't

Comment: You posted your private bot token. Revoke it with @botfather. Also note that the PTB team no longer supports ptb v13.x. You are strongly encouraged to upgrade to v20.x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that you are using an old version of python-telegram-bot, install a new version:

```
$ pip install python-telegram-bot --upgrade
```

Use the [quick start tutorial](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Extensions---Your-first-Bot)  to write your first bot, it's easy!

And your posted your private API token for Telegram, please revoke it in [@BotFather](https://t.me/botfather) and create a new one.

Good luck!